# How do I save the average of a column in a table in my database in a variable?

Tags: php, mysql

I can not save the average of a single column in a table in a variable in my java.
This is my php code:

```
<?php
  $connect = mysqli_connect("*******", "******", "******", "******");
  $response = SELECT AVG (value) AS (average) FROM (rate1)
  echo json_encode($response);
 ?>
```

My table is called rate1 and is formed by a column called fair values except where you type double. I would like to figure out how to write a php code and to take the values of the column value, average the values, and then enter this value in a variable in Java code; I was wondering if someone wants to help me; thanks for the replies and sorry for my English.

Comment: Really unclear what you are asking. Also there is no need for android tag

Comment: php has typo `;` and you sure about query is working and java code is missing

Comment: Could you please post your table schema to make sure that column name and table is valid. And also please put semicolon as mentioned by @PavneetSingh

Comment: Agree with @bub, no need for the android tag here. We don't need to know the device you are calling the API from.

Comment: @SachinSarawgi php is full of typos and errors like , typo query , should be string , no execution of query , code is just errors

Comment: My table is called rate1 and is formed by a column called values where i store double values. I would like to figure out how to write a php code and to take the values of the column value, average the values, and then enter this value in a variable in Java code; I was wondering if someone wants to help me; thanks for the replies and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.query.php) you can find more examples how to query a DB from PHP.
Here's what you probably need:

```
<?php
  $connect = mysqli_connect("*******", "******", "******", "******");
  $response = mysqli_query($connect, 'SELECT AVG(value) AS average FROM rate1');
  $result = array();
  if ($response) {

    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($response)) {
        $result[] = $row;
    }

    /* free result set */
    mysqli_free_result($result);
  }

/* close connection */
mysqli_close($link);
/* output formatted result */
echo json_encode($result);
?>
```